# Typescript cannot find module with new syntax

Tags: typescript

if I use;

> import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'

there is no problem but whan I change it to

> import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform/browser'

its underlined red and says "cannot find module.."

how can I fix this?
my tsc -v output is 2.0.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet you are using phpstorm or webstorm. Go to settings and in typescript section choose proper tsc bin

Answer (score 0):

Your reference to the corresponding Angular 2 modules is incorrect. In Angular 2 releases, the module names and syntax have been changed.

In Angular 2.0+, you can either use the following snippet to bootstrap with the JIT compiler,

```
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppModule} from './path/app.module';
platformBrowserDyanmic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Or with the AOT compiler, use

```
import {platformBrowser} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AppModuleNgFactory} from './path/app.module.ngfactory';
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

You can always reference the latest Angular 2 documentation [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html).